# Intro. to Abstract Algebra (Nicholson): 0.3, Problem 14 - Issue with this textbook question?

Tags: functions

**If $\alpha: A \mapsto A$ satisfies $\alpha^2 = \alpha,$ show that $\alpha$ is on-to if and only if $\alpha$ is one-to-one. Describe $\alpha$ in this case.**

If $\alpha^2 = \alpha,$ is not $\alpha$ the identity function and therefore invertible and bijective? Is it possible for $\alpha$ to satisfy $\alpha^2 = \alpha$ and not be injective or surjective?

$\alpha^{-1}\alpha^2(x) = \alpha(x) = \alpha^{-1}\alpha(x) = x,$

Thanks!

Comment: A projection on a vector space $V$ onto a proper subspace $W$ would satisfy $p^2=p$, but not be bijective.

Comment: For example, $\alpha : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 : (x, y) \mapsto (x, 0)$ is a map with $\alpha^2 = \alpha$, but it is neither one-to-one nor on-to. In particular, it's **not** the identity map.

Comment: So the rules of composition that I used to show that it is the identity map are wrong? Could you specify what I did wrong in the fifth line? Thank you :)

Comment: If $\alpha$ is not injective,  there is no inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A^{'} = \alpha(A)$ denote the image of $A$ under the idempotent $\alpha$.

The restriction mapping $\alpha^{'}:A^{'} \to A^{'}$ is the identity transformation.

Proposition: $A^{'} = A \text{ iff } \alpha \text{ is injective } \text{ iff } \alpha \text{ is surjective }$.

In tackling the $3\text{-chain}\implies\text{loop}$, the proof of two are trivial.

Assume $\alpha$ is injective and let $\beta$ be a left inverse. Then

$\tag 1 \alpha \circ \text{id}_A = \text{id}_A  \circ \alpha =  (\beta \circ \alpha) \circ \alpha =  \beta \circ (\alpha \circ \alpha) = \beta \circ \alpha = \text{id}_A  $

So $\text{id}_A$ is a right inverse of $\alpha$ and therefore $\alpha$ is also a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

This property, $f\circ f=f$, is known  as [idempotence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).  The image of each element of $A$ is a fixed point of $f$.